# Updating a google chrome extension in the webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there an API for uploading a chrome extension from a program, without having to open a browser?

I'd like an easier way of uploading an updated version - at present the process is clunky:

1. Find the developer dashboard
2. Push "Edit" on the extension
3. Push "Update File"
4. Click "choose file", and browse manually to the location, since the control is not native, so doesn't support drag and drop
5. Push "Upload"
6. Go back to the previous page, and push save

I'd like to be able to write a little script to do this for me, but I have no idea what URLs I should be requesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that in March Google published [an api](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) to do this.

I can't take credit for discovering this; that belongs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872077/2336725).  I also have not yet used the api.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to pragmatically update items in the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 0):

I just made this. Using the [Jitbit macro recorder](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNENUIVffJRrxZXQyNL9TyJ89l74iA)

Change the edit url to your own extension's one, change the browser titles to wait for and it should run anywhere.

The last part is of the script (starting from open changelog.php) is for automagically appending the last line of the changelog into the details, you can leave this out if you don't have a changelog that you update regularly. Otherwise, create a little script that returns this.

```
OPEN WEBSITE : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/cdfkaloficjmdjbgmckaddgfcghgidei?hl=en&gl=NL
WAIT FOR PROCESS : chrome : appear : 0 : 0
DELAY : 500
IF WINDOW EXISTS : Sign in - Google Accounts - Google Chrome : 0
MESSAGE BOX : Please select google account and sign in
DELAY : 500
WAIT FOR : Chrome Web Store - Google Chrome : appear : 0 : 0
WAIT FOR USER : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0
ENDIF
WAIT FOR : DuckieTV - 'Browser action' mode - Edit Item - Google Chrome : appear : 0 : 0
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
DELAY : 20
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
DELAY : 20
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
DELAY : 20
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
DELAY : 20
Keyboard : Space : KeyPress
WAIT FOR : Upload - Developer Dashboard - Google Chrome : appear : 0 : 0
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Space : KeyDown
DELAY : 84
Keyboard : Space : KeyUp
WAIT FOR : Open : appear : 0 : 0
TYPE TEXT : c:\wamp\www\deploy\browseraction-latest.zip
Keyboard : Enter : KeyDown
DELAY : 83
Keyboard : Enter : KeyUp
WAIT FOR : Open : disappear : 0 : 0
Keyboard : Tab : KeyDown
DELAY : 69
Keyboard : Tab : KeyUp
DELAY : 712
Keyboard : Space : KeyDown
DELAY : 100
Keyboard : Space : KeyUp
WAIT FOR : DuckieTV - 'Browser action' mode - Edit Item - Google Chrome : appear : 0 : 0
OPEN WEBSITE : http://localhost/duckietv/changelog.php
WAIT FOR : Changelog : appear : 0 : 0
DELAY : 2000
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
Keyboard : A : KeyPress
Keyboard : C : KeyPress
DELAY : 500
Keyboard : F4 : KeyPress
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyUp
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : Tab : KeyPress
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
Keyboard : F : KeyPress
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyUp
TYPE TEXT : Changelog:
Keyboard : Escape : KeyPress
Keyboard : End : KeyPress
Keyboard : Down : KeyPress
Keyboard : Enter : KeyPress
PASTE
```

Answer (score -3):

Just simply go to the extention's page (chrome://chrome/extensions/) and press ctrl+r.