# How to automate publishing Chrome extension to the Web store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Starting from Google Chrome 21.x private update sites won't be supported anymore. This forces us to move our extension to the Google Web store. Previously, we used an automatic script that created .crx file, signed it, and uploaded to the update site.

Is there a way to do script uploading extension to the Google Web store?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @sorin, Not yet, unfortunately..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a google chrome extension in the webstore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228935/updating-a-google-chrome-extension-in-the-webstore)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Since March 2014](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/03/new-monetization-and-publishing-options_11.html), there is an API to do that. Documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api).

I never worked with it, so I cannot provide a full example.

However, from the documentation, the basic flow would be an authenticated [request with an updated package](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#uploadexisitng), followed by an authenticated [request to publish](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#publishpublic):

```sh
> curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  \
-H "x-goog-api-version: 2" \
-X PUT \
-T $FILE_NAME \
-v \
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$APP_ID

> curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  \
-H "x-goog-api-version: 2" \
-H "Content-Length: 0" \
-X POST \
-v \
https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$APP_ID/publish
```

Comment: Looks like its an API that can be used from a controlled server or from the workstation but not from a CI for example.

The Code retrieved by to authenticate and get the access token can only be used once. The refresh token is needed to make any calls after 40 mins. As a consequence it needs to be stored, This type of state cannot be stored in a CI.

Basically a server using this should never go down/or store the token on disk.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my grunt plugin for this https://github.com/c301/grunt-webstore-upload.

But you still have to upload your extension first time, in order to get the extension id.

It solves only the uploading problem, you need to compile the ZIP file first. You can use this grunt plugin https://github.com/oncletom/grunt-crx ( I didn't test it ).

Comment: You, sir, are a hero.

Comment: Somebody made it available as regular npm package, in case you want to use it outside grunt: https://github.com/arieljannai/webstore-upload

Answer (score -4):

Actually, you cannot do it because of security issue. But you can build your extension to zip file automatically, then you just upload that zip file to Google Web Store. That's all!

Comment: The security excuse doesn't make any sense, if you really want you could automate it anyway.