# Uploading multipile Apps to Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I wish to know how can i handle any auto-process of uploading a Chrome extension to the Web Store, 
We cannot do it manually because we are handling a large number of customers that has the same product with some minor differences. So it has to be different products.

Is there some API to upload Apps to the Chrome Web Store ? 
Or any other solution for this issue.

Related Docs :
https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish

Thanks,

Matan Levy,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automate publishing Chrome extension to the Web store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822975/how-to-automate-publishing-chrome-extension-to-the-web-store)

Comment: I've added an answer to the question linked by Rob W