# Completely automate publishing of an extension to Google Chrome Web Store for CI-CD

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I want to continuously integrate a chrome extension I made, which means that I want to be able to easily publish it to the chrome store with a single CLI command.
I found [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/#usingtheapi) that explains well how to setup an API call to Google Web Store.
The issue I have is at the step **Testing your OAuth application**. Their method forces us to authorise it through our google account, hence, needing to click something to get the code.
I would like to automate this step.

I tried to fetch the url through curl but it gives this output:

```
➜  hub-browser-extension git:(github-actions) ✗ curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\?response_type\=code\&scope\=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore\&client_id\=$CLIENT_ID\&redirect_uri\=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?opparams=%253F&amp;dsh=S-2080034630%3A1700001959885153&amp;client_id=CLIENT_ID&amp;o2v=1&amp;redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fchromewebstore&amp;service=lso&amp;theme=glif&amp;flowName=GeneralOAuthLite&amp;continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fsignin%2Foauth%2Flegacy%2Fconsent%3Fauthuser%3Dunknown%26part%3DAJi8hANg-eObfogUqjbqJ8fgjb3xGuGymO2aAvEM9VICpmQe50fJKcyKsOaCyU3MLXRJ69x9yQqWoyQEMBVBwDFOBBgDBP339VNvQAieB6NFw1-OHT5YQX4fvMVPNwUqV7J8puxIj50OIstKG2MeHmU6cXfkf_XtQXj6HdfCCU-mzYtyUlkFrg4SnBTYnVi8c14hKB0ax0%26as%3DS-209885153%26client_id%3DCLIENT_ID%26theme%3Dglif%23&amp;rart=ANgoxce9Tz2ib71b-RbC6asPHrXoCSRRDil7EULMAdvmSh1E6KxjxSEjM">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I changed the tokens values in the output because they are sensitive data, but it is more or less the same.

Is there a way to get the code through CLI ? I am not interested in bot-based answer. Like I guess I could code a selenium bot but this would be more a hack than anything...

Thank you

PS:

- I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822975/how-to-automate-publishing-chrome-extension-to-the-web-store) which is close, but it doesn't mention the tricky part that interests me
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153708/deploy-to-google-play-store-via-api) is close too (and the answer makes me pessimistic) but not the same neither

Comment: FWIW, see how the existing uploaders do it e.g. in github actions.